# Pull vs Push for distributed servers

Tags: java, linux, cassandra, distributed

I am having servers in different data centers which are very far geographically

All the servers pull data from cassandra at regular intervals and then load it in internal memory

The servers a have a thread which reads data from cassandra.

I have noted an issue that for servers far from the cassandra cluster the thread which loads data from cassandra takes long and often the whole server gets into a halt.

I have thought of several possible solutions:

1. replicate cassandra so that servers communicate to cassandra which is near
2. move out the thread which reads from cassandra outside the server in form of a process
   So there will be a separate process which reads data from cassandra on each server and then pushes data to server running on the same machine

Will moving cassandra pull code as process instead of a thread in the server process improve things?

How will things turn out if i use push to servers instead of pull from servers ?

Please suggest some alternatives or suggestions on what factors affect the design choice

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There're no details in your question about why you chose this solution and if you tried Cassandra's replication. Before going with any custom replication:

1. I'd try to use the default
2. I'd need to understand what didn't work in the default